# How to get access to a collection inside the start collection by using a StreamBuilder

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, stream

I would like to know how can I get access to the fields of a collection that is inside the start collection? (see image below)

This is the `streamBuilder` I use to get access to the start(first) collection (`posts`) but I want a way to transform this `streamBuilder` so that I can get access to another collection inside the `posts` location. Thank you

```
StreamBuilder(
          ///IF YOU WANT TO CHANGE THE COLECCTION LIST THIS IS THE PLACE TO DO IT
          stream: Firestore.instance.collection('posts').snapshots(),
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            ///THIS IS THE PLACE WHEN YOU CAN ADD AN ANIMATION
            if (!snapshot.hasData) return const Text('Loading...');
            return ListView.builder(
              itemExtent: 100.0,
              itemCount: snapshot.data.documents.length,
              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                Post post = Post.fromDoc(snapshot.data.documents[index]);
                return _buildUserTile(post);
              },
            );
          },[![enter image description here][1]][1]
        ),
```

I want to be able to get the data that is inside a colection inside the first colection (`posts`).

See below my firebase database

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but maybe you can get an idea from the below link:

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/flutter-dev/ayIxrLiz1eQ